# How do I distribute an Arraylist to 2 other Arraylists?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to distribute `ArrayList< String >` into two other `ArrayList< String >`'s

So basically I have one `ArrayList` named `players`

> > ArrayList< String > players = new ArrayList<>();

And then I have two other `ArrayList`s named `teamBlue` and `teamRed`

> > ArrayList< String > teamBlue = new ArrayList<>();
> >
> > ArrayList< String > teamRed = new ArrayList<>();

And basically I need to somehow be able to go through the `players` list and distribute the contents evenly (sometimes `players.size()` will not be an even number, but it's fine to have not 100% even distribution)

I appreciate any help that you can give me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreach with a counter. When the counter is even, add the corresponding String to an ArrayList, when it's not add it to the other one.

```
int counter = 0;
for(String s : players){
    //check the value of the counter and add the String to the corresponding list
    //increment the counter
}
```

You could also use a traditional for loop (using `get` on the `ArrayList` with the index), but I prefer a foreach as it uses an `Iterator` behind the scenes so you don't depend of the current `List` implementation (and can improve performance, ex. `O(n²)` for a `LinkedList` instead of `O(n)` for an `ArrayList`)

Comment: Thank you very much! The code I ended up with is here: http://pastebin.com/Btqv1u1S

Comment: @bernhardkiv Seems fine, I would use a foreach instead of a traditional loop.

Comment: For each is my favourite control structure :D

Answer (score 1):

Just cut the list in half, right in the middle.  No need to iterate through the list.

```
int length = players.size();
List<String> teamBlue = players.subList(0, length / 2);
List<String> teamRed = players.subList(length / 2, length);
```